# Herencia en C++ y problemas con variaciones de reiniciar()

Tags: c++

Lo primero uso *C++11*. Tengo una clase base llamada *Area* que tiene una función virtual pura no definida llamada reiniciar().

Luego tengo dos clases derivadas, una llamada *AreaRectangular* y otra llamada *AreaCircular*.

El problema es que estas, además de implementar su propia definición de *reiniciar()* cada una tiene un *reiniciar()* adicional diferente de la otra clase derivada:

```
AreaCircular& reiniciar(Posicion2D pos, double radio); // de AreaCircular

AreaRectangular& reiniciar(Posicion2D pos, Tamanyo2D tamanyo); // de AreaRectangular
```

El problema que tengo es que no puedo invocar ninguna de estas dos funciones mediante un puntero a la clase base, ya que la única versión que reconoce es la de *reiniciar()* sin parámetros.

Había pensado en poner estas dos versiones de *reiniciar()* en la clase base también y hacerlas virtuales puras pero es que entonces las clases derivadas heredan un método que no quiero porque obligan a retornar un objeto de una clase derivada distinta.

En resumen. ¿Cómo puedo usar un puntero a Area para invocar la versión de reiniciar() que yo quiera dependiendo del tipo de objeto apuntado?

Mensaje de error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Area::reiniciar(Posicion2D&, Tamanyo2D&)'
note: candidate: virtual Area& Area::reiniciar()
note: candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

Añado la declaración de la clase base:

```
// PredeClarar Clases
class AreaRectangular;
class AreaCircular;

// Clase Base
class Area
{
public:
    virtual ~Area() = 0;
    virtual Area& reiniciar() = 0;
    virtual bool colisiona(Posicion2D pos) const = 0;
    virtual bool colisiona(AreaRectangular pos) const = 0;
    virtual bool colisiona(AreaCircular pos) const = 0;
    virtual int getX() const = 0;
    virtual int getY() const = 0;

};
```

Comment: He añadido la declaración de la clase base

Comment: Muy buenas respuestas si señor, me habeis aclarado un monton de dudas y la solucion que habeis propuesto no es muy dificil de implementar. Nos veremos por aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varias cosas:

**Las interfaces mejor en estructuras**

Vale que en C++ no existe el concepto de interfaz... pero fíjate que `Area` es una clase virtual pura... no tiene implementación de ningún tipo. Dado que todos sus miembros son públicos es preferible usar `struct`, cuya visibilidad por defecto es pública:

```
struct Area
{
    virtual ~Area() = 0;
    virtual Area& reiniciar() = 0;
    virtual bool colisiona(Posicion2D pos) const = 0;
    virtual bool colisiona(AreaRectangular pos) const = 0;
    virtual bool colisiona(AreaCircular pos) const = 0;
    virtual int getX() const = 0;
    virtual int getY() const = 0;
};
```

**Usa polimorfismo**

```
struct Area
{
    virtual bool colisiona(AreaRectangular pos) const = 0;
    virtual bool colisiona(AreaCircular pos) const = 0;
};
```

Eso está **MAL**. Se supone que `AreaCircular` y `AreaRectangular` heredan de `Area`... luego tener estas dos funciones implica que la clase base tiene que conocer a las clases que heredan de ella... ¿Y cuando tengas más tipos de áreas qué vas a hacer?

La solución pasa por usar polimorfismo:

```
virtual bool colisiona(Area const& pos) const = 0;
```

Esta función es perfectamente capaz de sustituir a las dos anteriores. Como recibe una referencia (similar a un puntero), accedes al objeto original y, dentro de la función, puedes preguntarle por su tipo concreto.

> El problema que tengo es que no puedo invocar ninguna de estas dos funciones mediante un puntero a la clase base, ya que la única versión que reconoce es la de reiniciar() sin parámetros.

Obviamente no vas a poder... cuando declaras una función como virtual el compilador tiene que crear una tabla (que permanece oculta al programador) con información sobre la clase y punteros a las funciones virtuales. Esta tabla se actualiza en las clases derivadas y es así como funcionan las funciones virtuales (en vez de hacerse una llamada directa a la función se llama al puntero a función que se encuentra en esta tabla).

La solución pasa por, como ha comentado [@Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/153815/463), por convertir los tipos, que por cierto también se puede hacer con `dynamic_cast`:

```
Area *ptr = ... // puntero a la clase base.

if( auto tmp = dynamic_cast<AreaRectangular*>(ptr) ) {
  // Ya podemos llamar a la función que queramos.
  tmp->reiniciar( ...argumentos... );
} else if( auto tmp = dynamic_cast<AreaCircular*>(ptr) {
  // Ya podemos llamar a la función que queramos.
  tmp->reiniciar( ...argumentos... );
}
```

Por cierto... no has puesto la implementación de ningún `reiniciar`... pero no tiene demasiado sentido que devuelva una referencia porque... ¿referencia a qué objeto?

- Si es a sí mismo no tiene sentido porque ya estás manejando el objeto tu mismo, luego no necesitas la referencia:

  ```
  AreaCircular area;
  Area& area2 = area.reiniciar(); // area2 apunta a area... no es necesario
  ```
- Si resulta que `reiniciar` crea un objeto interno y lo devuelve... al ser una referencia se borrará justo después del `return` y antes de que la ejecución abandone la función... luego vas a obtener una referencia a un objeto que no va a ser válido **nunca**:

  ```
  AreaCircular& AreaCircular::reiniciar()
  {
    AreaCircular area2;
    return area2;
  } // Al llegar este punto se destruye area2

  AreaCircular area;
  AreaCircular& area2 = area.reiniciar(); // referencia a objeto destruido
  ```

No veo necesidad alguna que justifique que esa función deba retornar nada... pero como te digo no veo la implementación así que solo te aviso de los posibles efectos adversos (legibilidad o acceso no válido) que puedes obtener al dejar la función tal y como está.

Comment: Si, reiniciar() retorna el mismo objeto y con casi todas mis clases he cogido la mania de hacer algo como cin, que promociona a bool para ver su estado y que ademas permite encadenar llamadas. Me cuesta implementar las versiones const porque se me dificulta inicializar cosas de la SDL2 y he tomado algunas decisiones drasticas basadas en el desconocimiento y coger una y ya esta. Pero bueno que como el proyecto tiene fin luego lo compartire y ya me aconsejaran para realizar todo ese tipo de cambios generales. Eso si, tu respuesta es util para aquellos que la visiten. Un saludo @eferion

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Cómo puedo usar un puntero a `Area` para invocar la versión de `reiniciar()` que yo quiera dependiendo del tipo de objeto apuntado?

No puedes.

---

C++ es un lenguaje de tipado fuerte, a grandes rasgos esto significa (entre muchas otras cosas) que un dato de un tipo no es (ni puede ser) un dato de otro tipo. Por lo tanto si tienes un puntero a `Area`: sólo podrás llamar a los métodos públicos de `Area` ni más ni menos.

Así que si tu objetivo es llamar a los métodos de una clase derivada de `Area` lo que necesitas es un dato (instancia, puntero o referencia) a dicha clase; por suerte es posible convertir datos de clase base a clase derivada (y viceversa):

```
Area *a = new AreaCircular{};
static_cast<AreaCircular *>(a)->reiniciar(Posicion2D{}, .0);
```

Es fácil y directo, pero puede ser problemático si en el puntero `a` no hubiéramos tenido un `AreaCircular`, por suerte podemos usar una conversión dinámica en lugar de una estática:

```
Area *a = new AreaCircular{};
if (AreaRectangular *ar = dynamic_cast<AreaRectangular *>(a))
{
    ar->reiniciar(Posicion2D{}, Tamanyo2D{});
}
```

La conversión dinámica (`dynamic_cast`) nos devolverá un puntero nulo si la conversión no es posible (o lanzará `std::bad_cast` si estamos convirtiendo referencias), de esta manera podremos esquivar el problema de convertir punteros que no deberían ser convertibles.

Por lo tanto tu pregunta puede ser respondida con el siguiente código:

```
// Función de ayuda, para escribir menos
template <typename D, typename B>
D *b2d(B &b) { return dynamic_cast<D *>(&b); }

Area &reiniciame(Area &a)
{
    if (auto ac = b2d<AreaCircular>(a))
        return ac->reiniciar(Posicion2D{}, .0); // de AreaCircular
    else if (auto ar = b2d<AreaRectangular>(a))
        return ar->reiniciar(Posicion2D{}, Tamanyo2D{}); // de AreaRectangular
}
```

El problema de la conversión dinámica es que suele tener un impacto apreciable sobre el rendimiento del programa, por lo que suele aconsejarse evitarla si no es estrictamente necesaria... lo que me lleva a:

#### Consejo.

Olvida el polimorfismo en este contexto, desde mi punto de vista es una [sobreingeniería](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobreingenier%C3%ADa); el polimorfismo es una herramienta para tratar de manera genérica (base) tipos específicos (derivados) y en tu caso no necesitas tratamientos genéricos si no específicos ergo: estás usando la herramienta incorrecta para tu problema; por otro lado tus objetos son extremadamente sencillos:

```
struct AreaCircular {
    Posicion2D pos{};
    double radio{}
};

struct AreaRectangular {
    Posicion2D pos{};
    Tamanyo2D tamanyo{};
};
```

Permite que el compilador trabaje por ti para seleccionar el tipo de colisión adecuado, usando sobrecarga (que viene a ser un tipo de polimorfismo) de funciones libres:

```
// Punto contra rectángulo
bool colisiona(const Posicion2D &pos, const AreaRectangular &ar);
// Punto contra círculo
bool colisiona(const Posicion2D &pos, const AreaCircular &ac);
// Punto rectángulo contra círculo
bool colisiona(const AreaRectangular &ar, const AreaCircular &ac);
// ...
```

Comment: Vaya me has dejado alucinado muchas gracias Paula.

Comment: Es curioso que te den las gracias por decir que estás haciendo las cosas mal ;P

Comment: Lo que se de programacion hasta ahora lo he aprendido yo solo y por eso para mi estas respuestas valen oro y es que en todo este tiempo no las he tenido. Seguir asi que estais ayudando a mucha gente, tu el eferion y todos los que estais.